# Ограничиваем доступ в админку

Tags: php, route, laravel-8, middleware

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста! Как скрыть ссылку от обычного пользователя, что бы ссылка было видна только администратору сайта.
Вот пример как я скрывал ссылку от пользователей

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
  Ссылка видна только админу
@endif
```

В **Middleware** есть файл **CheckIsAdmin.php** в этом файле следующий код:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckIsAdmin
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(!Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return redirect()->route('index');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Route** прописан следующим образом:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isadmin', 'admin'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
});
```

Когда вставляю код в шаблон **.blabe**

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
ссылка
@endif
```

ссылка исчезает как у администратора, так и у пользователя сайта. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить это действие?

Comment: потому что для отслеживания сессии пользователя, на тех или иных маршрутах,где это должно быть, нужно использовать middleware `web`, иначе auth::check всегда будет false как и ваша проверка

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov
Подскажи пожалуйста как или где правильно нужно использовать middleware `web` ?

Comment: ну в данном случае на группу

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov
`Route::group(['middleware','web' =>` Так?

Comment: ну просто к своим добавьте ещё один, перед auth например

Comment: Для начала прочитайте как [регистрируется прокладка](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#registering-middleware) и как её [использовать](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-middleware) в проекте и в [Blade шаблонах](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-blade-templates).

Comment: Где-то ошибку допускаю. Жаль.